# Understanding the ".send" warning message

Tags: solidity, compiler

`Warning: Failure condition of 'send' ignored. Consider using 'transfer' instead.`

Is this a new compiler warning, and what exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transfer` reverts in the case that the call to the address given fails. `send` on the other hand doesn't, and instead returns true/false for a success/failure. If you don't do anything with that failure condition, then you get that warning